# How to Change the Starting Position of Text Context in WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

How the change the **default** starting text content position like the upper TextBox to the lower TextBox.

[image]

Comment: If you set the padding property to 0, you can reduce that space a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the left-padding to 0 and the TextBox will look as described:

```
<TextBox Padding="0,5,5,5" ... />
```

I'm not sure, but the default padding may be 3, so:

```
<TextBox Padding="0,3,3,3" ... />
```

MSDN has a good article on [Alignment, Margins, and Padding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx).